# Accuracy for forecasted value in R

Tags: forecasting, forecast-combination

I forecasted a combined model with using full data set. Problem is when I use test data set my accuracy coding works fine but when I use the same for my combined data set with full data set it does not work.
Coding:

```
combo.model.full <- yosemite.new %>%
  model(ets=ETS(yosemite1),
        lets=ETS(log(yosemite1)),
        larima=ARIMA(log(yosemite1)),
        arima=ARIMA(yosemite1)) %>%
  mutate(combination.1=(larima+arima)/2)

combo.full.fore <- forecast(combo.model.full, h=12)

combo.full.fore %>% autoplot(level=NULL)+
  labs(title="Comparing forecast with full data", x="month",
       y="number of visit")

accuracy(combo.full.fore, yosemite.new) %>% arrange(RMSE)
```

but it shows the comment :

```
Warning message:
The future dataset is incomplete, incomplete out-of-sample data will be treated as missing. 
12 observations are missing between 2023 Jan and 2023 Dec .
```

Anyone can tell what to do find the best model.